# retrofit get request returns null

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I use extract articles from news api and display them using paging 3 library in my project, but for some reason @GET request returns my response class but with null variable though on my profile on the news api site it shows that there was a request.

NewsApi class:

```
interface NewsApi {

companion object{
    const val CLIENT_ID = "356d64b4bfde4cd492ef415beabba030"
    const val BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/"
}

@Headers("X-Api-Key: ${CLIENT_ID}")
@GET("v2/everything")
suspend fun searchArticles (
    @Query("q") query: String,
    @Query("page") page: Int,
    @Query("pageSize") pageSize: Int,
) : NewsResponse
```

}

My Response class:

```
data class NewsResponse (
val results: List<NewsArticle>)
```

Comment: That’s not possible because the return type is not nullable. It will either return an instance of the Response class or throw an exception. What is convincing you the return value is null? How are you retrieving it?

Comment: in description I said that it returns an object with null variable(list). just didn't want to explain that in the title

Comment: The list isn’t nullable either. Anyway, you might first try making the same request in a web browser to see if you get your expected response.

Comment: in browser it works

Comment: can you please share the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your api and fetch the result,
Your Api is fine, the problem is you try to get the result as

```
data class NewsResponse (
val results: List<NewsArticle>)
```

when the result is actually formed like this :

```
{
"status":"ok",
"totalResults":14925,
"articles":[
{
"author":"Igor Bonifacic",
"title":"University of ",
"description":"In aide built a robot to com…"
}
]
}
```

so change you result into :

```
data class NewsResponse(
    val status : String,
    val totalResults: Int,
    val articles: List<NewsArticle>
)

data class NewsArticle(
    val author: String,
    val description: String
)
```